# Is there any iOS slide on top sidebar?

Tags: ios, slide, sidebar, hamburger-menu

I want a slide in hamburger sidebar in iOS. But I dont want the sidebar to push the view like in the facebook app or MMDrawerController. I need the side bar to be on top of the view.

Is there any controllers for this task?

I am looking for something like this [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not UISplitViewContorller?

Comment: https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

Comment: @Bhavin the one you suggested is the exactly what I am looking for. But I need that in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Objective-C version of the suggested Swift Project. Use this https://github.com/Pluto-Y/SlideMenuControllerOC